# Building Image from Dockerfile fails on ppc64 when using COPY --FROM

Tags: docker

Currently i have image build process via jenkins that launches agents on ppc64le and x86 architecture.

Currently everything works perfectly on the x86 agent, but when executing on ppc64le it fails with the error described bellow:

Error that only happeons on ppc64le:

```
 ---> Running in 5458becfaa7b

/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: ELF: not found

/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: @8�@8: not found

/usr/bin/apt-get: 8: /usr/bin/apt-get: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy install     python3     python3-dev     python3-numpy     python3-scipy     python3-pip     libkeyutils1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 2

script returned exit code 2
```

The sections where it fails:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

## Install random tests
COPY --from=appt /usr/ /usr/
COPY --from=appt /bin /bin

RUN apt-get -qq update \
&& apt-get -qqy install \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    python3-scipy \
    python3-pip \
    libkeyutils1 \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy from `COPY --from=appt` is causing issues because it contains non-ppc64le executables. `apt-get` must be running something from either the `/usr` or `/bin` directories.